# Under what conditions does $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $f$ is a real function defined on an interval of the form $(a,\infty)$. If the corresponding sequence $\{f(n)\}_{n=k}^{\infty}$ converges to some real number $L$, what conditions on $f$ would allow me to deduce that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$, if any exist?

In general, this statement is clearly false; a counterexample is given by $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$. For all positive integers $n$, $f(n)=0$, and so $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist. That being said, I have a strong feeling that one should be able to deduce the existence of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ for at least *some* functions.

Thinking about some potential conditions for this statement to be true, I noticed that all the functions I thought about were differentiable over an interval of the form $(a,\infty)$ for some $a>0$, and that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ for each, leading me to speculate that this might be a potential answer to my problem. However, I don't know how to prove this, much less where to start.

**Context**: Recently, I challenged myself to prove all of the most important facts about exponential functions using their [axiomatic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function) (Characterizations > 5 > anywhere-continuous). Right now, I am attempting to prove that they are all differentiable at $0$, that is,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$$

exists, since this implies that they’re differentiable everywhere. Using results from this post, it is (perhaps) sufficient for me to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)\text{ and }\lim_{n\to \infty}-n\left(a^{-\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$$

both exist.

Note: I am **not** asking for a way to prove that

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$$

exists, so unless you want to point out a flaw in my approach, please don't include hints nor answers to this latter problem in your responses. I really want to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Well basically if you already know the function converges at $\infty$, for example if it's monotonic and bounded, or if it's Cauchy, then the sequence can tell you the value of the limit.

Comment: @paxtibimarce I never thought of that! That's really clever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits are equal under the condition that eventually for any $x\in[n,n+1)$ a suitable bounding for the function holds, that is for example for $L\in \mathbb R$

$$\min(f(n), f(n+1))\le f(x) \le \max(f(n), f(n+1))$$

or for $L=\infty$

$$ f(x) \ge f(n)$$

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the *oscillation* of a function, see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)

For an interval $[a,b]$, the oscillation $\omega_f([a,b]) = \sup_{[a,b]} f - \inf_{[ab]} f$.

Then the conclusion will hold if
$$
\limsup_{m \to \infty} \omega_f((m,m+1)) = 0
$$

A sufficient condition is
$$
\limsup_{m \to \infty} TV_{[m,m+1]}(f) = 0
$$
where $TV$ is the *total variation* of $f$.